# word for "upper middle class"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, finance

In the USA, UMC roughly means annual income of $1**000, with enough wealth to own a large house and other comforts, but not enough to own a congressperson.

Some words that don't seem right:

- [bourgeoisie](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/148711/modern-use-of-bourgeoisie)
- proletariat, common people - *not financially secure*.
- wealthy, elite, a-list - *upper class*.
- gentry, aristocracy - *upper class and British*.
- establishment - *own congresspeople*.

Example usage: "No, the {upper middle class} is not 'the establishment'."

A phrase is acceptable if it has fewer characters and syllables than "upper middle class".

Comment: How much is $1**000?

Comment: Is this question solely about the American English meaning of the phrase? In Britain the definition of "upper middle class" is a LOT more complicated than annual income.

Comment: @nohat $100000-$199000

Comment: @JeremyC any English-speaking origin is acceptable if it's not slang and conveys "well off but not rich or powerful".

Answer (score 1):

One way to describe this class or lifestyle is "well-off." That's a very wide range, but I would say it's above "working class" or "middle class," but not rich or super rich (although many rich people may call themselves simply well-off to downplay their wealth).

Some examples:

"Welfare for the well-off" (Stephen Moore, 1999)

"A total of 67.5 percent of the Block Grant funds of well off communities were directed at these national objectives...." (The Housing Authorization Act of 1976: Hearings Before the United States Congress. 1976)

"First, that almost two-thirds of well-off respondents are gratified seems appropriate, since in the aggregate their class is thriving. ("Facing Up to the American Dream: Race, Class, and the Soul," Jennifer L. Hochschild - 1996)